# Does browsing black magic and spells make someone mushrik?

Tags: shirk, sihr

Does it fall under committing shirk when browsing stuff of black magic on the internet and checking out spells.

if it does fall under shirk, is it minor or major sin and how can you repent for it and does allah forgive one.

Comment: I don't know the answer to the first part of your question. But even if it is major shirk, just ask Allah for forgiveness, and it is expected that He will forgive you provided that your repentance is correct. You can read this: http://islamqa.info/en/20482

Answer (score 2):

Shirk is if you believe in other divinities besides Allah.

In Surah adh-Dhariyat 51:51 =

> And do not make with Allah another deity. Indeed, I am to you from Him
>   a clear warner.

The word **إلَه** translated as "deity" means something that is divine.

If you believe anything besides Allah is divine, then you've done Shirk whether you worship or not.  Shirk has already taken place.

Browsing stuff on black magic isn't shirk unless you BELIEVE in its divinity.  And it wouldn't be sinful just by reading it unless you tried to do black magic.

And I should add that not all Muslims believe in the existence of black magic.

*Sihr* or black magic literally means something which has an unknown reaction or cause.  if I put money in your pocket without you knowing, this can be called *Sihr*.  I simply tricked you and you don't know how.

So if someone claims black magic to be Shirk needs to really provide clear-cut evidence from Quran and Sunnah.